# Strategies for Rails development/test development with complex legacy schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, legacy-database

When developing a Rails app with a legacy schema that is in-use by an existing application, if tables have NOT NULL constraints on foreign id columns throughout the schema, in order to create/save models for tests, models need to exist for those associations, and their associations, etc. So, it isn't an easy as just creating one model at a time as you need it and testing with it.

As far as testing goes, this seems to be a problem if you are using FactoryGirl and want to create and save model instances to return from controllers, etc. when all of the association dependencies are involved. Another option is to mock, but mocking can be a little more time consuming and it doesn't allow you to do integration testing as easily. Another is to use fixtures, but those are time consuming and brittle. Another is to pre-populate the test database with production data, but that doesn't solve the need for factories, etc./known data to expect in tests, and Rails usually expects to start with a clean DB for the test environment.

What strategies for developing models, tests, etc. do you use when you have an existing complex schema that you are bolting a Rails app onto- not just for reading data, but also writing to the existing schema that is in use by an existing production application? (i.e. the "rebuild the ship while at sea" problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we first started out on this problem, I was looking for something that could autogenerate models from the existing schema. I found Dr. Nic's magic model generator, but it only stated that worked in Rails 2.x. I got a Rails 2.x environment running (forget the specific version it worked in) but it didn't seem to help much, so I wrote a script to generate our models. However, when we started development we then had a load of models, so we started to try to move out the ones we didn't need, then needed to comment out associations to models that were no longer there, but some of those were required/NOT NULL foreign keys, so we're now having to move them back in and uncomment those more than we thought we would.

We did write and uncover some things that were helpful during the process, not all of which we've used, but they might be helpful to others:

- https://github.com/influitive/apartment
- https://github.com/karledurante/secondbase
- https://github.com/drnic/composite_primary_keys
- https://github.com/garysweaver/activerecord-define_nils
- https://github.com/garysweaver/activerecord-native_db_types_override
- https://github.com/garysweaver/modelist
- https://github.com/garysweaver/stepford
- https://github.com/garysweaver/structure_sql_to_migration

As for test data setup, I started writing a tool to automate the development of FactoryGirl factories called [Stepford](https://github.com/garysweaver/stepford) and wrote [Modelist](https://github.com/garysweaver/modelist) to help us test models, resolve circular dependencies, and identify model dependencies, so we don't have to include all automatically generated models.

So far really, the only answer I've come up with and have heard other say also is that rebuilding an existing application, even piecemeal, with different technologies is difficult, slow, and error-prone.